# Eclipse Layout Editor Reference Chooser missing @id options

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Since upgrading to Eclipse Helios and SDK 10 I seem to have lost all references to @id/fields in the layout editor Reference Chooser.  I can see Layouts, Drawables & Strings only. 
These used to be there (& in fact still are on my other machine running Eclipse 3.5) Is anyone else having this problem?  Is there something that needs to be switched on etc to make this work. Or is it now a feature? :(
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this issue the other day on the google group for android.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers?hl=en

It said someone has filed a bug for this a couple of weeks ago. They replied "It seems to be broken. We'll look at it."
Just have to edit the id's manually until its fixed!

Comment: Pah! That's not fun :( Thanks for the response - I'll have to just keep typing :(